# Converting byte[] to Image C# (ArgumentException Error)

Tags: c#, stream, type-conversion

(I use Google Translate, sorry..) 
I'm trying to do a small project with shorthand.
I found similar topics, but they are not what I need.
The bottom line is, I get an image at the input, convert it to byte [], then to binary. (Everything is OK here)
Then I translate the text to binary. (Everything is OK here)
in the binary array, I change the last two bits to the ones I need.
I translate everything back to byte[] (everything is OK Here)

and then I try to convert byte[] to Image and an error occurs (Incorrect argument)

If I do not make changes to binary, the conversion is successful ( and I get the same image that I gave at the input).

change code in the binary array:

```
public byte[] ShifrMessage(byte[] input, string message)
        {

            byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string str, Encoding encoding)
            {
                return encoding.GetBytes(str);
            }

            String ToBinary(Byte[] data)
            {
                return string.Join("", data.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')));
            }

            //message in the binary
            var binaryString = ToBinary(ConvertToByteArray(message, Encoding.ASCII));

            byte[] ret = new byte[input.Length];


            for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
            {
                string a = Convert.ToString(ret[i], 2).PadLeft(8, '0');


//changing the last two bits
                if (binaryString.Length >= 2)
                {
                    a = a.Substring(0, a.Length - 2) + binaryString.Substring(0, 2);
                    binaryString = binaryString.Substring(2);
                }
///

                byte b = StringToByte(a);
                ret[i] = b;
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

I assume that when converting to Image, the integrity of the image that was changed is checked.

conversion:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {
            using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms1);
            }
        }
```

Can you tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: What does all this code do? I don't understand the goal of all the string manipulation.

Comment: Please add the exception message and stacktrace.

Comment: I want to encrypt the text in the image. So I converted the image to binary[]. Next, I replace the last two bits. And then I'll convert it back to Image/

Comment: System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Сообщение = Недопустимый параметр.
  Источник = System.Drawing
  Трассировка стека:
   в System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   в System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)